# RAID: dedicated and distributed parity

Tags: data-structures

I understand what parity is (Sort of): 
A data recovery mechanism where missing data is calculated based on the data that exists. However i have encountered terminology which i can't define or put into perspective of the RAID system.

This terminology is 'dedicated' and 'distributed' Parity. Now i imagine that it is somehow related to the distribution of data among separate disks, but **can anyone give a more detailed definition and explanation of 'Dedicated' and 'Distributed' parity?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question can be infered from the [wWikipedia page on
"Standard RAID levels"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels).

Parity is just one simple case of techniques for error detection, and the name
seems to be used here to stand for various techniques of error
detection and correction.

The idea of dedicated vs distributed parity, is related to whether the
redundancy of information is on a special dedicated disk or whether it
is distributed over all disks of the RAID system.

This does not apply to RAID 1 where redundancy is achieved by simple
duplication of Data.

In the case of RAID 3 (and apparently RAID 2), data is [striped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_striping) (read
"spread" for faster access) over several disk why the redundancy data
(parity bytes or bits) is in a separate **dedicated** disk.

In the case of RAID 5, the redundancy is spread over all the disks and mixed into the original base data
(**distributed parity**) so that the original data can be retrieved
from any set of n-1 disks, when any one of the n disks fails. The
content of the failed disk can be recomputed from the n-1 others.

Distributed parity seems to be preferred to dedicated parity, though the
wikipedia page is not really clear as to why. My own suspicion is that
it allows for more effective error correction than dedicated parity, which keeps the original data and the redundancy (parity) data separate.
But this should be checked.

Comment: the advantage is balancing the write-read load among the disks.

Comment: @RanG.I gathered that from the wikipedia page, but I did not see why.. In both cases you have to read from all the disks, if you are to check for errors.

Comment: right, but if you change some value, you also need to change the parity. If all parities sit at the same dedicated disk - you will keep accessing it all the time, with every write. (now the wear of the dedicated disk is multiplied w.r. to the other disks)

Comment: @RanG. I am missing a piece of information regarding the data organization and updating (possibly related to striping). But I guess comments is not the proper mean to investigate that. Thanks.